# Help identifying pattern in these number sequences for closed form Taylor Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

In my research, I am trying to evaluate an integral in closed form.  I realized that if I can write the following function:

$$ \text{erf}\left(x\right)^{k+1}$$

as a Taylor expansion centered at zero, then I can evaluate the integral in series form, which would be great!  I used Mathematica to find the derivatives and evaluated them at x=0 and got the following:

\begin{equation}
\[\begin{array}{l}
k = 0\\
\frac{{{d^n}}}{{d{x^n}}}{\left[ {{\rm{erf}}{{\left( x \right)}^{k + 1}}} \right]_{x = 0}} = \left\{ {0,\frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }},0, - \frac{4}{{\sqrt \pi  }},0,\frac{{24}}{{\sqrt \pi  }},0, - \frac{{240}}{{\sqrt \pi  }},0,\frac{{3360}}{{\sqrt \pi  }},0, \ldots } \right\}\\
k = 1\\
\frac{{{d^n}}}{{d{x^n}}}{\left[ {{\rm{erf}}{{\left( x \right)}^{k + 1}}} \right]_{x = 0}} = \left\{ {0,0,\frac{8}{\pi },0, - \frac{{64}}{\pi },0,\frac{{896}}{\pi },0, - \frac{{18432}}{\pi },0,\frac{{509952}}{\pi },0,-\frac{17940480}{\sqrt{\pi}},0,\frac{771194880}{\sqrt{\pi}},0,-\frac{39305871360}{\sqrt{\pi}} \ldots } \right\}\\
k = 2\\
\frac{{{d^n}}}{{d{x^n}}}{\left[ {{\rm{erf}}{{\left( x \right)}^{k + 1}}} \right]_{x = 0}} = \left\{ {0,0,0,\frac{{48}}{{{\pi ^{3/2}}}},0, - \frac{{960}}{{{\pi ^{3/2}}}},0,\frac{{25536}}{{{\pi ^{3/2}}}},0,\frac{{ - 895488}}{{{\pi ^{3/2}}}},0, \ldots } \right\}\\
k = 3\\
\frac{{{d^n}}}{{d{x^n}}}{\left[ {{\rm{erf}}{{\left( x \right)}^{k + 1}}} \right]_{x = 0}} = \left\{ {0,0,0,0,\frac{{384}}{{{\pi ^2}}},0, - \frac{{15360}}{{{\pi ^2}}},0,\frac{{688128}}{{{\pi ^2}}},0,\frac{{ - 37355520}}{{{\pi ^2}}}, \ldots } \right\}
\end{array}\]
\end{equation}

The goal is to find the Taylor Expansion of each k, and then hopefully find a general formula which relates them all.  I will address convergence after this is done.

For k = 0, if we start a new index $n$ at $n=1$,the pattern seems to be recursive:
$$a_1 = 2$$
$$a_n = 2(2n-3)a_{n-1}\;\;\;\;\;\;n\ge 2$$

Thus the taylor expansion is:
$$ \text{erf}\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}a_n}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}$$

I plotted this against the function and verified that it does indeed seem to be correct.  I am stuck at k=1.  Can anyone help identify any of the above patterns for k>0?

For k=1, at first glance it seems very similar, but breaks down by the 4th term. Namely (previous term in parenthesis), first term is 8, then next is 8*(8), next is 14*(8*8) so seems like multiplier is going up by 6 each time.  But the next term is 17920 which is wrong.

Any thoughts?

Comment: For $k = 1$, your deduction is  incorrect. First term: $8 = 1\times8$, second term: $8\times 8 = (1+ 7)\times 8$, third term: $14\times8\times8 = (1 + 7 + 6)\times8\times 8$, and so the multiplier is _not_ going up by $6$ _each_ time. Perhaps you should write out a few more terms?

Comment: I added a few more terms!

Comment: It would be better to consider the Maclaurin series, rather than the sequence of derivatives.  The you can multiply it by itself to get the Maclaurin series for the powers.  I don't know if you get a nice closed form though.

Comment: @an4s Yes, I realized that and deleted my comment.

Comment: It seems like for $k=1$, every number is divisible by 8.  Dividing each number by 8 gives:  $\{ 1,8,112,2304,63744,2242560,96399360,4913233920,.... \}$.  If a pattern can be found from these multipliers then that series can be found.